# Is the norm $\|A\|_\mathrm{op}$ for a matrix $A$ a Euclidean norm?

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

$\displaystyle \|A\|_{\operatorname{op}} = \sup \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$ for  $v$ in $V$, where $\|v\|$ is a Euclidean norm of a vector $v$ in a vector space $V$.

I saw a counter-example that was based on the fact that  $\|a+b\| \leq\|a^2+b^2\| - \|a^2-b^2\| $ is true for all Euclidean norms. Is this right? Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "Euclidean norm", I take it to mean a norm that arises from an inner product. It is known that a norm on a vector space arises from an inner product if and only if it satisfies the *Parallelogram Law*: 
$$ 2\|x\|^2 + 2\|y\|^2 = \|x - y\|^2 + \|x + y\|^2$$
You should be able to find matrices $A,B$ such that the operator norm does not obey this equation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!